# Count all 2D non-black objects

Tags: opencv

I have a solid black background in a couple of images and there are objects inside of those pictures (non-black objects but multi-colored).

How can I count the amount of non-black objects (they are surrounded by black pixels and do not collide with each other)?

I thought of making this completely from scratch (going through the pixels and when finding a non-black one, search around it to know its limits and count it as one, keeping the limits so I'll know when it's not the same one as when I iterate through every line of pixels I will collide with the same object again). But I wondered if there's an easier way to implement this using OpenCV.

[image]

Comment: Future reference: You can upload images directly to your question instead of spammy image hosting sites.

Comment: You should add your OpenCV version and the programming language you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), or if you're on OpenCV > 3.0, you can also use [connectedComponents](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a&gsc.tab=0).

You need to first convert your image to grayscale:

```
// Load image
Mat3b img = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\random.png");

// Convert to grayscale
Mat1b gray;
cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

and then binarize it. Since your background is black (grayscale value 0), you can simply consider as foreground all pixels with value greater than 0:

```
// Binarize image
Mat1b bin = gray > 0;
```

Then simply retrieve connected components:

```
// Find connected components
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(bin.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

cout << "Number of connected components: " << contours.size();
```

You can eventually draw each connected component with a different random color:

```
// Draw results
Mat3b results(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0,0,0));
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
{
    Scalar color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
    drawContours(results, contours, i, color, CV_FILLED);
}

imshow("Results", results);
waitKey();
```

resulting in:

[image]

Full code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Convert to grayscale
    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Binarize image
    Mat1b bin = gray > 0;

    // Find connected components
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(bin.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    cout << "Number of connected components: " << contours.size();

    // Draw results
    Mat3b results(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0,0,0));
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        Scalar color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
        drawContours(results, contours, i, color, CV_FILLED);
    }


    imshow("Results", results);
    waitKey();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: by the way, it doesn't seem to work well with [this](http://postimg.org/image/9srnc7o6f/835a0455/). Any idea why? no pixel is pure black rather than the background

Comment: because that image has jpeg compression artifacts. Use a higher threshold to remove background: `Mat1b bin = gray > 20;` seems good to me

Comment: Thank you! `gray > 25` seemed to do the work over here

Answer (score 0):

using OpenCV you can use the function Count Contours (i.e. your shapes outlines). I have included a link to the description and a tutorial link.

You should first convert to a BW image then use this function.

[Find Contours Description](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), [Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but any chance of marking the answer as useful, please? I occasionally jump on the site but still can't comment on posts yet.